# Dynamically created divs not showing next to each other

Tags: javascript, css

I am dynamically creating divs and I want them to appear next to each other. I have the following code and after applying style to it (line 5) they keep showing one of top of the other. Please help.

```
rmc.onstream = function (e) {
    if (e.isVideo) {
        var uibox = document.createElement("div");
        uibox.appendChild(document.createTextNode(e.userid));
        uibox.className = "userid";
        uibox.id = "uibox-" + e.userid;
        uibox.style.cssText = 'display: inline-block; float: left';
        document.getElementById('video-container').appendChild(e.mediaElement);
        document.getElementById('video-container').appendChild(uibox);
    } else if (e.isAudio) {
        document.getElementById('video-container').appendChild(e.mediaElement);
    }
    else if (e.isScreen) {
        $('#cotools-panel iframe').hide();
        $('#cotools-panel video').remove();
        document.getElementById('cotools-panel').appendChild(e.mediaElement);
    }

};
```

Comment: What is `e` supposed to be?

Comment: inline block and float?

Comment: Using `display: inline-block` and `float: left;` is unnecessary; I suggest you choose which one is ideal for your situation, but don't leave both, as inline-block will have no effect whatsoever when using float.

Answer (score 0):

Your styles are only being applied to `uibox`, and you need to apply them to `emediaElement` too:

```
if (e.isVideo) {
        var uibox = document.createElement("div");
        uibox.appendChild(document.createTextNode(e.userid));
        uibox.className = "userid";
        uibox.id = "uibox-" + e.userid;
        uibox.style.cssText = 'float: left; width: 50%';
        e.mediaElement.style.cssText = 'float: left; width: 50%';
        document.getElementById('video-container').appendChild(e.mediaElement);
        document.getElementById('video-container').appendChild(uibox);
}
```

Here is a working pen - I had to modify your code since I can't see where `e.mediaElement` is coming from, but you can get the idea: http://jsbin.com/woluneyixa/1/edit?html,css,js,output

If you're still having issues, please create a working codepen so we can see the problem you're having.

Also, using `display: inline-block` and `float: left;` is unnecessary; inline-block will have no effect whatsoever when using float.

Comment: I edited my code to what you have but for some reason they keep showing one on top of the other. These divs have video in them, I don't know if that makes a difference.

Comment: Updated pen: http://jsbin.com/duqibuqoxi/1/edit

Updated answer code as well. The content will only float side by side if there is room for it